# Curl is zero when I have radial symmetry?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

I'm trying to understand why, when we have radial symmetry of a vector quantity, the curl of this quantity is zero. For example, I have a sphere. I know that the polarization of the sphere, which is just a vector quantity, has radial symmetry. Does this means that the curl of this quantity, the curl of the polarization, is zero? Why?

Comment: Well, $\vec{\nabla}\times f(r)\vec{r}=0$ because $f(r)\vec{r}=\vec{\nabla}g(r)$ with $g'=rf$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rephrasing the comment from @J.G, the spherical symmetry  means that curl of a vector with a spherical symmetry  $\vec{a} = f(r) \vec{e_r}$ will be:
\begin{equation}
 \mbox{curl} \, \vec{a} = \nabla \times \vec{a} = \nabla_r \times f(r) \vec{e_r}
\end{equation}
The nabla operator. It is easy to show that $f(r) \vec{e_r} = \nabla_r g(r) = \nabla g(r)$ and finally
\begin{equation}
\mbox{curl} \, \vec{a} = \nabla \times \nabla g(r) 
\end{equation}
and the operator $\nabla \times \nabla$ is known to be zero

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. You wrote that $\mbox{curl}\; \vec a = \nabla g$ and you also wrote that $\mbox{curl}\; \vec a = \nabla \times \nabla g$.

Comment: If you are paraphrasing J.G.'s comment, I think you want to write $f(r)\vec e_r = \nabla g(r)$ not $\nabla \times f(r)\vec e_r = \nabla g(r)$

Comment: Yes that is true, thank you for the remark. I have corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to understand why, when we have radial symmetry of a vector quantity, the curl of this quantity is zero.

Assuming, "radial symmetry" means you are looking at a field of the form:
$$
\vec F = f(r) \vec r,
$$

Then you have
$$
\left(\nabla \times \vec F\right)_ i = \epsilon_{ijk}\nabla_j \left(f(r) \vec r_k\right)
$$
$$
=\epsilon_{ijk}\left(f'(r)\frac{r_j r_k}{r}+f(r)\delta_{jk}\right)
$$
$$
=0\;,
$$
since both $r_j r_k$ and $\delta_{jk}$ are symmetric and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is antisymmetric.